# InvokeAll method using corePoolSize instead of maxPoolSize

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, threadpoolexecutor

I have an application where I need to ingest data into ES. There are multiple rows so I am using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to parallelize the  ingest of data in batches of 50. Also, I am getting this data in my consumer and I do not want to ack before I have processed all the records so I have encapsulated the task in a `Runnable` class and I adding them to a list of callables and using invokeAll() when the list has all the data.

maxPoolSize of my `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is `200` and `corePoolSize` is `50`. So, I was expecting the application to use `200` threads at one time as by my understanding `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` uses threads upto to `corePoolSize` when queued up tasks are less than the `corePoolSize` and later it starts adding threads upto the `maxPoolSize` and executes the tasks. When, I checked in my logs and visualVm I found out that only `50` threads were executing, So, I increased the `corePoolSize` to `70` and found out that `70` threads were executing. Where as queue size should be more than 3000 as the list is more than 3000 thousand. Sample code for the issue.

```
public void Test() throws InterruptedException {
List<Callable<Object>> tagList = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>(1000);
for(int i=0; i<400; i++){
  tagList.add(Executors.callable(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     System.out.println("Thread "+ Thread.currentThread());
     try {
       Thread.sleep(4000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }));
}
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().invokeAll(tagList);
}
```

INFO  | 2021-02-14 00:06:32.086+05:30  | Application |  134 | current thread count: 50 total thread count: 200

INFO  | 2021-02-14 00:06:33.085+05:30 | Application |  134 | current thread count: 50 total thread count: 200

Please can someone explain if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maxPoolSize of my ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is 200 and corePoolSize is
> 50.So,I was expecting the application to use 200 threads at one time as by my understanding ThreadPoolTaskExecutor uses threads upto to
> corePoolSize when queued up tasks are less than the corePoolSize and
> later it starts adding threads upto the maxPoolSize and executes the
> tasks.

That is not quite right. As it is the case with [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> When a new task is submitted (..), and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle.
> **If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize
> threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is
> full.**

Hence, the reason why you have only 50 threads running even though the maxPoolSize is `200`.

From [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) one can read:

> The default configuration is a core pool size of 1, with unlimited max
> pool size and unlimited queue capacity. This is roughly equivalent to
> Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), sharing a single thread for all
> tasks. **Setting "queueCapacity" to 0 mimics
> Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), with immediate scaling of threads in
> the pool to a potentially very high number.** Consider also setting a
> "maxPoolSize" at that point, as well as possibly a higher
> "corePoolSize" (see also the "allowCoreThreadTimeOut" mode of
> scaling).

It looks like you have to set the `queueCapacity` to zero in order to meet your requirements.